# Как открыть окно, в котором скрипт Python формата "exe" вывел информацию и потом завершил свою работу

Tags: python

Как открыть окно, в котором скрипт Python формата "exe" вывел информацию?
И как остановить окно ,в котором выведена информация, что бы оно не исчезало сразу после завершения программы?

Comment: У скрипта питона нет формата ехе. Ответ на второй вопрос находится поиском по этому сайту.

Comment: я скомпилировал скрипт в формат exe. Он запускается выводит какую-то информацию и окно исчезает. Мне нужно посмотреть что в окне. Так как скрит до компиляции до конца работает. После компиляции почему-то не до конца выполняется.  Поэтому не имеет смысла ставить в конце  скрипта input().

Comment: Это решается если везде использовать системные потоки вывода(в т.ч. в модулях). Т.к. это невозможно, то берете запись экрана и покадровой разбиваете. Там ищете нужную вам картинку. И да, Python интерпретируемый язык. Pyinstaller И прочие только лишь собирают все в один пакет

Comment: а как тогда выполнить трассировку скрипта формата exe ? Запись экрана как-то слишком не программно. Нужно какую-то прогу ставить